# Button onClick method works on second click only

Tags: android, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have trouble on `onClick` method in my activity. I use `layoutInflater` in `onClick` method and change layout to another layout on button click, that's ok. But i have a my own method in `onClick`. It doesn't work on first click. It works only on second click.

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getTextA();
    mFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.soru, null);
    mFrameLayout.addView(v);
    Button bt = new Button(this);
    bt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mFrameLayout.addView(bt);
    bt.setText(textA);
}
```

`textA` comes from `getTextA()` method, but on second click. Why ? Anyone can help me ?

Comment: What's in your getTextA() ?

Comment: I bet that is yet another who is not understanding multithreading... And getTextA just start some async call... As in bazillion similar questions.

Comment: It is just a presumtion. OP looks like he's new to android dev from his score.   getTextA() will not work if it is getting text from bt button because it is not set yet on first call (another presumtion).

Comment: @yusuf korkmaz - looks like you did not show enough of your code so we can't tell why it's not working. Please edit your question if you still need help, for example share the code for getTextA()

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem. Problem is in layoutinflater inside onClick method. So i put that layoutinflater codes to new method call getQuestion(). And call getQuestion() method in my getTextA() method. its solved.

I use layoutinflater because this method still in a fragment. Using a new fragment causes Nestedfragments. Thanks for your answers.

Here is the code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    getTextA();
}`

public void getTextA(){
  //Method details.
  getQuestion();
}

public void getQuestion(){
mFrameLayout.removeAllViews();
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.soru, null);
mFrameLayout.addView(v);
Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mFrameLayout.addView(bt);
bt.setText(textA);
}
```

Comment: *Problem is in layoutinflater inside onClick method* looks like Million Monkeys Programming Style... Now you are not calling old getTextA at all. The real problem is that you are not getting `textA` value before you use it